# Does addFilterQuery require parantheses?

Tags: java, solr

I'm writing a solr query that is attempting to do some geo filtering.

I've run the query with parentheses and without parentheses and got different results.

Without parantheses:

`fq={!geofilt pt=lat,long sfield=geo d=num} OR {!geofilt pt=lat2,long2 sfield=geo d=num}`

With parantheses:

`fq=({!geofilt pt=lat,long sfield=geo d=num} OR {!geofilt pt=lat2,long2 sfield=geo d=num})`

Does the query need parentheses to do the OR properly or does it not?

Answer (score 0):

Yes the query does need parentheses. Without parentheses it returns the same result as `{!geofilt pt=lat,long sfield=geo d=num}`.